# MonoGame - scale down a sprite from the middle

Tags: c#, monogame, vector, scale

I want to animate a texture's scale. First it's scaled up to 10, and then it gradually goes down to 1. However the texture is drawn at `Vector2(0, 0)` so it doesn't animate as I had imagined it would - it should scale down from the center of the texture. I'm sure the `origin` has something to do with it but I just can't figure out the math I need to use. So the texture is 1366x768 pixels, just as the entire screen. So here's what I tried:

```
private Texture2D texture;
private Vector2 origin;
private float scale = 10.0f;

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    scale -= 0.05f;
    if (scale <= 1.0f)
    {
        scale = 1.0f;
    }
    origin = new Vector2(texture.Width * scale / 2, texture.Height * scale / 2);
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0.0f, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
}
```

When I debug this, I can't even see the image (the game is fullscreen). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't apply the scale to your origin calculation. Just as the texture has fixed dimensions- the center of the texture remains at the center as wel.

I wrote an extensive answer about spritebatch and the role of the origin parameter as answer to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/127688/understanding-spritebatch-draw-overload-xna).

Comment: With the code I currently have, and the removal of the scale from the origin equation, the image animates like this: from bottom-right to top-left, and then it stops as the image center point hits the top-left-most point of the screen. Ideas on how to fix that? All I want is a way for my logo to have that zoom-out effect and stop when it's fully visible... I'm going to read the question you linked and attempt to find a solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that the origin also relates to where the texture is positioned. Position your texture to the center of the screen and set the origin to the center of the texture.

Comment: To think, that was something I tried... but with the scale in the origin equation. This solves the problem.